# Need to assign an event listener to the tab key using keycodes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, event-listener

I have currently an eventlistener listening for when a user enters an email address in a textbox on an html website. It then displays an alert when it detects an email address is being entered. Currently I have set it up whereby it detects the event blur then checks whether it meets the regex then an alert will display. This creates many alerts and is not very accurate as the alert

I need the eventlistener to listen for when the tab key specifically is pressed. I know I need to use KeyCodes but have not used them before. This eventlistener is currently working dynamically as it is a Firefox AddOn that scans a webpage so the eventlistener is not specifically attached to a specific input box.

Code:

```
vrs_getWin.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = bodyContents;
    var inputFields = vrs_getWin.document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(inputC=0; inputC < inputFields.length; inputC++)   {
        var elementT = inputFields[inputC].getAttribute("id");
        inputFields[inputC].addEventListener("blur", function(){
            var emailPattern = /(\w[-._\w]*\w@\w[-._\w]*\w\.\w{2,3})/g;
            var resultEmail = emailPattern.test(vrs_getWin.document.getElementById(elementT).value);
            if(result)  {
               prompts.alert(null, "Test", vrs_getWin.document.getElementById(elementT).value);         
            }
        }, false);
    }
```

Any help with this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think from a UX stand point, I would not recommend using a javascript alert to notify the user of a problem, especially if you want the notification to happen when they have completed a single form input.  The blur event would be my recommendation, and use some other visual cue to notify the user.

But, if you want to go with the tab key, the event your looking for is 'keydown', or 'keyup'.  To use it you listen for the keydown event then check if the event.keyCode == '9'. (tab key)

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                if( e.keyCode == '9' ){
                    alert('You pressed the tab key.');
                }
            }, false);
```

To get the keycodes of keys I like to pop open a console and type in:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                console.log( e.keyCode );
            }, false);
```

Then when you press a key, it will output the keycode for that key.

Comment: When you say visual cue what do you mean?

Comment: Here's one I found that illustrates it. https://www.typepad.com/secure/services/register?acct_level=pro